# how to avoid flicker when two events are fired

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have written a code where I have configured the OnPageShow(event) for checking if the page is from cache. If the page is from cache, I reload the same page for hitting the server. But while doing this, there is a screen flickering issue. The reason is When I click the browser back button, first the page from cache loads and is displayed, and then after complete loading it goes in the OnPageShow method which again refreshes the page. Is there any way to avoid the flickering issue ?

Here is the code:

```
function RefreshloadWindow()
{
    if(!(window.performance && window.performance.navigation.type == 2))
    {
        console.log("In On Load");
        GetLatestBreadcrum();
    }
}
function GetLatestBreadcrum()
{
    console.log("In Breadcrum function");
    var matches=[];
    var divElements=document.getElementById("breadCrumDiv").children;
    console.log(divElements);
    var j=0;
    for(i=0;i<divElements.length;i++)
    {
        //console.log(divElements[i].tagName);
        if(divElements[i].tagName=="A")
        {
            matches[j]=divElements[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    for(z=0;z<matches.length;z++)
    {
        console.log(matches[z]);
    }
    var lastElement=matches.length;
    //matches[lastElement-1].click();
    window.name=matches[lastElement-1];
    console.log(window.name);
}
function IsPagePersisted(event)
{
    if(event.persisted || window.performance && window.performance.navigation.type == 2)
    {
        //console.log("From Cache 2");
        var iLink=document.createElement('A');
        iLink.href=window.name;
        GetLatestBreadcrum();
        iLink.click();
    }
}
```

And Body tag is as follow:

```
<body onpageshow="IsPagePersisted(event)" onload="RefreshloadWindow()" >
```

Comment: Please share the code that you have for this

Comment: Side note - when you update your post the commenters are not pinged automatically. If you want to ping them (good practice) add a comment with @

Comment: ok. I didn't knew about it. Thanks for informing.

Comment: So you do not want to show the old page when user navigates back? And the page should be showed only after the reload?

Comment: @Deividas Exactly

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to show the page initially you can add
`"display: none;"` to the body tag and then remove that style after the reload.

Comment: Yes, you're correct.But I've designed a filter mechanism which gets messed up when cache entry comes. So I need to reload the page at least to take care of the filters. Until the page is refreshed, it wont hit the server to take care of the filters.